# Why Nagios command not running from Thruk?

Tags: centos, monitoring, remote-server, nagios, shinken

I have few Nagios commands, one of the command is showing "CRITICAL" status on Thruk with a message of "Could not execute command." Where as when i try to execute the same command from terminal, is shows correct status with correct message.

This is happening only for few commands. Please help me on it.

Comment: Try run your command as user who running your Nagios. Maybe problem with permission.

Comment: Same user is running command and this is happening only with WMI queries, for which i am using "check_wmi_plus.pl" [link] (https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Windows/WMI/Check-WMI-Plus/details) file.